# SVG height with D3.Js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I got a little problem, i got actually many tree's who are aligned side by side horizontaly, the problem is when the three's have a different height, they are not aligned horizontaly correctly. Help me please to find a solution, thanks ! :)

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root,
    root2;

var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.x; });


var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "div")
    .attr("width", 1920);

var svg = div.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");

var svg2 = div.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg2")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");

var svg3 = div.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg3")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30 30)");

d3.json("c.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;
  root = d3.hierarchy(json);
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;
  update(root, svg, "svg");
});

d3.json("D.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;
  root = d3.hierarchy(json);
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;
  update(root, svg2, "svg2");
});


d3.json("c.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;
  root = d3.hierarchy(json);
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;
  update(root, svg3, "svg3");
});

function update(source, svg_var, svg_name) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

document.getElementById(svg_name).setAttribute("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_name);
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3.5)
      .attr("dx", 5.5)
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.attributes; });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg_var.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.links(), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  /*link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  root.each(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });*/
}


function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

D.json File :

```
{"attributes": "DPGF", "children": [{"attributes": "LOT:  nom 13.CVC", "children": [{"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 1", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 0.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 19.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle debut"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 21.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 23.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 24.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 25.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 26.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 27.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle production thermique"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 28.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 2", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 2", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 31.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Échangeur"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 2"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 3", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Manchon"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 36.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 36.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Vanne"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Thermomètre"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Sonde"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 39.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 39.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Soupape"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 40.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 41.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Pressostat"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 42.0"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

c.json file :

```
{"attributes": "OUI", "children": [{"attributes": "LOT:  nom 13.CVC", "children": [{"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 1", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 0.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 19.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle debut"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}]}]}]}
```

Try to resize the svg-height of the two c_file in the deboguer of your browser to see the final result that i'm waiting for, so we can see that the longer SVG (with the biggest height) start at the top of the page, and the others svg start at the bottom, but i need them all to start at the top of the page. Thanks you again for your help and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://ibb.co/ngo9S9 ?

Comment: Yes !!! How did you did ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the following solution

```
var cell;
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "div")
    .attr("width", 1920);
cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell")
var svg = cell.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");
cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell")
var svg2 = cell.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg2")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");
cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell")
var svg3 = cell.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg3")
    .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30 30)");
```

And a bit of CSS

```
#div { display: table-row; }
#div .cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
```

Your code will not run because `root` is undefined and you can't get `links` from it.

Answer (score 0):

I used simple CSS and removed `.attr("id", "div").attr("width", 1920)` which doesn't do anything anyway.

Here's the CSS I tried:

```
div#div {
  width: 1920px;
}
div#div svg {
 float: left;
}
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pgqbn4eIECncuqhBVp6U?p=preview

**Note**: I'm not a fan of assigning HTML element tag names as IDs and so I think an ID other than **div** would be a better option. It's your choice after all.

Comment: using `float` is old style CSS to align blocks. we now have much better options