# Cut the text in a rect in D3.Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a tree organization and on this tree, I have some rect, who have a `|` character. It means that the text that is written after this `|` must be placed at the end of the rect.

Here is the code (copy it for see the result):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Graphique DPGF</title>
    <style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

div#div svg {
    float: left;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root;


var path = [];   
path[0] = "D.json";
path[1] = "D.json";
path[2] = "D.json";
create_a_tree_obj(path);


function create_a_tree_obj(path) {
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    var svg_array = [];

    if (i === 0) {
        div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "div");
    }
    for (i ; path[i]; i++) {
        svg_array[i] = div.append("div").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "" + i)
        .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i);
    }
}


function add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i) {
    var root;

    d3.json(path[i], function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        for (; path[i]; i++) { 
            root = d3.hierarchy(json);
            root.x0 = 0;
            root.y0 = 0;
            update(root, svg_array[i], "" + i);
        }
    });
}    


function update(source, svg_var, svg_id) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    document.getElementById(svg_id).setAttribute("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id);
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3.5)
      .attr("dx", 5.5)
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.attributes; });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
}


function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

And here the D.Json file :

```
{"attributes": "DPGF", "children": [{"attributes": "LOT:  nom 13.CVC", "children": [{"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 1", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 20", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 0.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 19.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle debut"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 41", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 45", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 21.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 23.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 50", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 24.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 25.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 54", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 26.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 27.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle production thermique"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | Total = 94", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 28.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 2", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 2", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 31.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Échangeur"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 2"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 3", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Manchon"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 36.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 36.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Vanne"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Thermomètre"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Sonde"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 39.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 39.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Soupape"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 40.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel 41.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Pressostat"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel 42.0"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

So for the final result , I want to have something like this (we will say that my final rect wanted is on the quote, we got : before -> the final result wanted), so for example: "Poste: Rang Rang 1 | Total =20 spaaaaace_on_the_rect" -> "Poste: Rang Rang 1 spaaaacceeeee_on_the_rect Total =20". Thanks you again for the help guys and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @zahreddine - unfortunately we need specific questions about the problems you are having with your current implementation (and if at all possible a reproducible example). Please consider editing your question to focus on the specific issue you need help with.

Comment: Hi @Ian, my problem is simple but i didnt find how to do it in the web, can anyone help me so ?

Comment: Your problem is explaining what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had created a Plunkr for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283688/svg-height-with-d3-js?noredirect=1#comment91518330_52283688) you posted before, I've made changes to the same code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Pgqbn4eIECncuqhBVp6U?p=preview

**Relevant code changes:**

Changed the text adding logic to the nodes

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .each(function (d) {
    if(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|') > -1) {
      var beforeText = d.data.attributes.substr(0, d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')).trim(),
        afterText = d.data.attributes.substr(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')+1, d.data.attributes.length).trim();

      d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('beforetext', true).text(beforeText);
      var afterTextSpan = d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('aftertext', true).text(afterText);

      // position aftertext
      var temp_text = svg_var.append('text').classed('temp_text', true).text(afterText);
      afterTextSpan.attr('x', barWidth-temp_text.node().getBBox().width+10)
      temp_text.remove();
    } else {
      d3.select(this).text(d.data.attributes); 
    }
  });
```

**Explanation:**

1. If `d.data.attributes` doesn't contain `|`, just set the text as is.
2. If it does contain `|`, use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to compute the strings before the `|` and after the `|` (set them to `beforeText` and `afterText` respectively.
3. As you need two texts at different positions, I'd recommend using `tspan`s and just changing the `x` positions (you could also do this by having 2 separate `<text>` elements)
4. No need to position the `beforeTextSpan` as it's supposed to be on the left side which it gets to by default. But for positioning the `afterTextTspan`, I've used a **temporary text** to compute the width of the `afterText` and minus it from the barWidth to offset the `tspan` to the right side of the rect. (this logic is useful for larger texts).

And by the way, I've used the CSS I mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283688/svg-height-with-d3-js?noredirect=1#answer-52296248) to align the SVGs. Hope this helps.