# Retrive all of the same classes from an existing "g" tag

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I got a svg that as a g tag with a lot of differents tags in it (text and tspan). I just wanna try to retrieve all classname who are named "aftertext". I tried this but i don't retrieve anything..

**svg** is the g tag in the svg. :

```
function add_total_svg(svg) {
    var all_aftertext = svg.selectAll(".aftertext");
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root;

var path = [];
path[0] = {"attributes": "DPGF", "children": [{"attributes": "LOT:  nom 13.CVC", "children": [{"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 1", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 | 100509", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 0.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 19.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle debut"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     40", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 20.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     44", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 21.0"},
{"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 23.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     49", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 24.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |25.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Préambule"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     53", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel |26.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |27.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle production thermique"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 1 |     93", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 28.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle chauffage"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 1"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 2", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 2", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 31.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel | 65.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Échangeur"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 2"}, {"attributes": "Tous_DPGF:  Profondeur 3", "children": [{"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 35.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel| 35.0"},
{"attributes":"Mot_cle Manchon"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel |36.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |36.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Vanne"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel| 37.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |37.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Thermomètre"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel    | 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel| 38.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Sonde"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel  |39.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel   |39.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Soupape"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel | 40.0"}, {"attributes":"Fin_poste_Excel |41.0"}, {"attributes":"Mot_cle Pressostat"}, {"attributes":"Rang Rang 4"}]}, {"attributes": "Poste:  Rang Rang 4", "children": [{"attributes":"Debut_poste_Excel             | 42.0"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]};

var value = [];
create_a_tree_obj(path);

   

 function add_total_svg(svg, globaldiv, cell) {
        var all_number = svg.selectAll('.node tspan.aftertext')
    .each(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });
    cell.attr("class", "total").attr("id", "total");
    cell.select("#title").text("Total");
    }

function create_a_tree_obj(path) {
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    var cell;
    var svg_array = [];
    
    if (i === 0) {
        div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "div");
    }
    for (i ; path[i]; i++) {
        cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell").attr("id", "cell");
        svg_array[i] = cell.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "" + i)
        .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i);
    }
    add_total_svg(svg_array[i - 1], div);
}

function add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i) {
    var root = [];
    
//    d3.json(path[i], function(error, json) {
//        if (error) throw error;
        for (; path[i]; i++) { 
            root[i] = d3.hierarchy(path[i]);
            root[i].x0 = 0;
            root[i].y0 = 0;
            update(root[i], svg_array[i], "" + i, root);
        }
//    });
}    

function update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    document.getElementById(svg_id).setAttribute("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d, e) {
      if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources); //recursion pour re-afficher la page dynamiquement.
    });
    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3.5)
    .attr("dx", 5.5)
    .each(function (d) {
    if(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        var beforeText = d.data.attributes.substr(0,   d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')).trim(),
        afterText = d.data.attributes.substr(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')+1, d.data.attributes.length).trim();

        d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('beforetext', true).text(beforeText);
        var afterTextSpan = d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('aftertext', true).text(afterText);

    // position aftertext
        var temp_text = svg_var.append('text').classed('temp_text', true).text(afterText);
        afterTextSpan.attr('x', (288 - afterText.length * 6) - 5)
        temp_text.remove();
    } else {
        d3.select(this).text(d.data.attributes); 
    }
  });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
}

//setTimeout(() => simulateClick(240, 141), 2000); //Click test worked
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}
```

```css
.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#div { display: table-row; }
#div .cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
    
.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

i only need to retrieve in a array all classes who are named "aftertext" (the blue rect with a number) ..

Comment: Can you apply some jsfiddle for that and explain more what you need?

Comment: The title doesn't match the actual question: _"retrieve all same id..."_ vs. _"retrieve all classname..."_

Comment: Here is a plnkr : "https://plnkr.co/edit/t9lalII0OkdeQ6CP4yJm?p=preview", i only need to retrieve in a array all classes who are named "aftertext" (the blue rect with a number) ..

Comment: What's wrong with: document.getElementsByClassName('aftertext') ?

Comment: I got a lot of tree's (who are in the svg) , and i need to retrieve the ('aftertext') of only one svg.. @PoulBak

Comment: Your question and comments don't make sense. Which tree or SVG are you trying to get the elements from? Please post the code (including the SVG) here, rather than on an external site.

Comment: Your the one who telled me when the code is too long, to don't put the all code here.. and i need to retrieve the number of the blue rect, who are the 'aftertext' class in the g tag -> into the text tag -> into the tspan tag (bit complicated, just check with the debogger when you click and inspect a blue rect with a number) ;) @ialarmedalien

Comment: No, that was someone else -- I would have told you to post a code sample here so that the question can be useful to others even if Plnkr disappears. Please read the SO documentation on the appropriate amount of code to post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I will edit your question to demonstrate the appropriate detail to include in the code sample. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks i take note of what you said for the future questions. :) @ialarmedalien

Comment: Are you planning to add up the contents of each of the `aftertext` cells? It would be a much, much better idea to get parse that data directly from the json before you create the visualisation.

Comment: I want to change the content of these aftertext cells, if i ask the question here, this is because this is my only solution to do it, i already tried to do it in Json but for my needs, it's better to do it on the javascript code directly. So is it possible to retrieve all of these aftertext cells in an array or not ? Thanks you @ialarmedalien

Comment: So anyone have a solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

Man, there's so much of confusion in the comments. Here's the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296985/cut-the-text-in-a-rect-in-d3-js) from where the **aftertext** comes into picture. I had answered that question and added the **aftertext** `tspan`s.

@zahreddine - I can understand that you're trying to improve your English but it'd be easier for the developers who've added comments to understand the issue if you would refer to the original post and mention the `tspan`s added in the answer and you just had to fetch those `tspan`s. Anyway, next time.

Coming to the solution, here's one approach to select all the `tspan` based on the **aftertext** class:

```
// printing all after-texts
svg_var.selectAll('.node:not(.child) tspan.aftertext')
 .each(function (d) {
    console.log(d);
 });
```

And regarding the `child` class in the above code, it's coming in from this addition which is to differentiate between child and parent nodes (as you say you're looking for just the **blue** rects but if you're looking for ALL aftertexts, just take out the `:not(.child)` selector):

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", function (d) {
   return 'node ' + (d.children ? '' : 'child'); 
 })
```

Using the above changes, here's a fork of the Plunkr (check the console for the desired output):

https://plnkr.co/edit/VSegZNp9uGkNj5VvLBAY?p=preview

I see that you're trying to sum up these retrieved values, that should be easier now. If you're unable to do that, create a new question and put in either the code or a fork of your Plunkr.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try to clarify my questions in the future for sure. I tried the first solution, but, when i tried to see what did i have on the `svg_var` with `console.log(svg_var)` , the browser show me that svg_var is actually an empty NodeList.. :(

Comment: That's weird. Did you check the console in the Plunkr link I referred to?

Comment: This is working but you putted your code in the `update` function, but i need to work this out on the `add_total_svg` function because on the future i will not only have one `svg_var` but three `svg_var`, and i will need to only work on the last svg, so, on the `add_total_svg` i already retrieve the last svg where i will need to do the modifications on it, but it doesn't work when I implement your code in this function and i dunno why.. @Shashank

Comment: @zahreddine I think you're making life more difficult for yourself by storing your references to SVGs in an array; it would be much simpler to use an object and index them by the SVG ID. That would make it very easy to identify the SVG and then retrieve the nodes that you want.